# How to use `--foo 1 --foo 2` style arguments with Python argparse?

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

`nargs='+'` doesn't work the way I expected:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument("--name", dest='names', nargs='+')
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--name'], dest='names', nargs='+', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args('--name foo --name bar'.split())
Namespace(names=['bar'])
```

I can "fix" this by using `--name foo bar`, but that's unlike other tools I've used, and I'd rather be more explicit. Does `argparse` support this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use `action='append'` instead of `nargs='+'`:

```
>>> parser.add_argument("--name", dest='names', action='append')
_AppendAction(option_strings=['--name'], dest='names', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args('--name foo --name bar'.split())
Namespace(names=['foo', 'bar'])
```

`nargs` is used if you just want to take a series of positional arguments, while `action='append'` works if you want to be able to take a flag more than once and accumulate the results in a list.